# how to open a different page when cancel button is clicked in the Confirm dialog?

Tags: javascript, scriptmanager

I just need to add an else condition in the following confirm function. So that if cancel is clicked on the box another page opens up.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    Me,
    GetType(Page),
    "confirm ",
    "{ confirm('Hello World'); window.location = 'page.aspx'  }",
    True
);
```

Any help in this regard would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    Me,
    GetType(Page),
    "confirm ",
    "{ if(confirm('Hello World')===false) { window.location = 'page.aspx' } }",
    True
);
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(
    Me,
    GetType(Page),
    "confirm ",
    "{
      var r = confirm('Hello World'); 
      if (r == true)
         window.location = 'page.aspx';
      else
         windo.location = THE_OTHER_PAGE;
     }",
    True
);
```